# Преобразование типов в Java

Tags: java

На вход у меня в программу поступают данные в таком формате: `-u id name sex bd`. `id` - номер, `name` - имя, `sex` - пол, `bd` - день рождения.

У меня есть **класс Person**, в который и добавляются все эти значения:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Sex sex;
    private Date birthDay;

    private Person(String name, Sex sex, Date birthDay) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }

    public static Person createMale(String name, Date birthDay){
        return new Person(name, Sex.MALE, birthDay);
    }

    public static Person createFemale(String name, Date birthDay){
        return new Person(name, Sex.FEMALE, birthDay);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Sex getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(Sex sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Date getBirthDay() {
        return birthDay;
    }

    public void setBirthDay(Date birthDay) {
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }
}
```

Есть еще такой **класс Sex**:

```
public enum Sex {
    MALE,
    FEMALE
}
```

Как мне передать все параметры из args в конструктор ? Вот так вот понятное дело не работает:

```
if (args[0].equals("-c")) {
    allPeople.add(new Person(args[1], Integer.valueOf(args[2]), args[3]));
}
```

Comment: Дополните вопрос примером передаваемых аргументов командной строки. В каком формате передаете sex и bd?

Comment: Если проблема с полем Date - используйте SimpleDateFormat для преобразования из String в Date. Если проблема с ENUM - сделайте метод, который по значению String параметра будет вам возвращать нужный Enum. Если вы намеренно решили закрыть конструктор(а он у вас private), то делайте проверку значения аргумента означающего пол(sex) и вызывайте ваши методы createMale/createFemale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый элемент массива args, передаваемого в метод main имеет тип String.

Строка

```
new Person(args[1], Integer.valueOf(args[2]), args[3])
```

Вообще не имеет смысла - у него нет конструктора Person(String, Integer, String).
Тот конструктора что есть - приватный, и из кода видно что планировалось создавать экземпляры через фабричные методы createMale и createFemale.

Необходимо явно создавать объекты нужного типа. Sex - в зависимости от значения параметра (лучше - через условное выражение, но можно и через Enum.valueOf()),
дату - через SimpleDateFormat.

Хотелось бы видеть полностью строку вызова, потому что непонятно откуда берётся

```
if (args[0].equals("-c"))
```

когда написано

> На вход у меня в программу поступают данные в таком формате: -u id
>   name sex bd

Answer (score 2):

Args: `-c name sex bd`

Constructor:

```
public Person(String name, Sex sex, int birthDay) {...}
```

Main:

```
if (args[0].equals("-c")) {
    Sex sex = Sex.MALE.name().equals(args[2]) ? Sex.MALE : Sex.FEMALE;

    allPeople.add(new Person(args[1], sex, Integer.valueOf(args[3])));
}
```

Comment: Поле типа Sex нужно получать вот так: `Sex.valueOf(args[2])`

Answer (score 2):

```
//предположу, что пол передается как male/female
//а дата как dd/MM/yyyy, тогда, опуская большую часть проверок

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(args[3]);

if (args[2].equals("male")) {
    allPeople.add(Person.createMale(args[1], date));
} else {
    allPeople.add(Person.createFemale(args[1], date));
}
```